# Batch: Open a specific file in a specific program?

Tags: windows, batch-file

How do i tell windows to open C:\test\test.txt in WordPad, when Notepad is my default program for .txt files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the direct path to the executable like

```
start C:\Windows\System32\write.exe [FILE]
```

Comment: ;) Works like a charm.
I am using the batch to run a file in Java's compiler.

Answer (score 18):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. I am not sure if it was because of the program I was trying to run, or because the path had spaces in (even though I wrapped it in quotes), or something else.

Anyway, I was able to do it be adding an empty string after the `start` command.

For example:

```
start "" "C:\My Programs\myprogram.exe" "C:\My Files\myfile.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
start wordpad c:\test\test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `start` when using `write.exe`, so simply:

```
write [FILE(S)]
```

`write.exe` is located in `C:\Windows\System32`.