# how to open unregistered file in not installed program via batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Firstly, I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132381/batch-open-a-specific-file-in-a-specific-program).

Now, I would like to open a file which has unregistered extension in the program which is not installed in windows, all via batch.

```
START "%~dp0\arch\file.nesta" "%~dp0\Virtua.exe"
rem this will open only program

pause

START "" "%~dp0\arch\file.nesta" "%~dp0\Virtua.exe"
rem and this will summon "Open in program" win window
```

Point is to drop a file into program with one (double) click.
(exe file and bat file ar in same folder while file is in "arch" subfolder)

Comment: You should specify the program you want to run first and any parameters for the program after. You should also use empty quotes for the TITLE when using the START cmd. `START "" "%~dp0\Virtua.exe" "%~dp0\arch\file.nesta"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Syntax for command START

[Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman) has given already the (nearly) right answer which I explain here in more details.

Running in a command prompt window `start /?` displays help for this command also described by Microsoft on page about command [start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) with entire [command line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) in menu on left side.

After command **START** there should be specified the `"title for command window"` in double quotes. This can be also an empty string specified with `""` if the application to start is a GUI application and not a command or console application. The title of the GUI window is always defined by the GUI application and not by command processor. So a meaningful title string instead of an empty title string makes sense only for console applications and commands of Windows command processor executed in a new console window.

A title string in double quotes is not necessary if there is no string on entire line enclosed in double quotes because no parameter string contains a **space** or a character from this list: `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` This character list is displayed at end of last output help page on running in a command prompt window `cmd /?`

Then one or more of the optional parameters of **START** itself must be specified on the line if one of those parameters is required for the task at all.

The next parameter must be the command or application to run as new process. **START** can be also used to just start a new command process with a new console window and therefore a command or application must not be specified. But **START** is used in in batch file **usually** to run an application in a separate process and not for just opening a new command prompt window.

And last are specified the parameters of the command or application to start.

**What does this mean in practice?**

---

#### Command START with one parameter in quotes

```
START "%~dp0\arch\file.nesta"
```

Command **START** creates in this case a new command process with `Drive and path of batch file\arch\file.nesta` as title for the new console window displayed in title bar of the window. So the single string in double quotes is interpreted by command **START** always as title string for a new command window.

---

#### Command START with two parameters in quotes in wrong order

```
START "%~dp0\arch\file.nesta" "%~dp0\Virtua.exe"
```

This results in starting `Virtua.exe` in directory of batch file with `Drive and path of batch file\arch\file.nesta` as title for the new console window in case of `Virtua.exe` is a console application.

But even if `Virtua.exe` is a GUI application, the string `%~dp0\arch\file.nesta` is already taken by command **START** as window title not being displayed anywhere and therefore `Virtua.exe` is always started with no parameter using this command line.

---

#### Command START with two parameters in quotes in right order with missing required title string

```
START "%~dp0\Virtua.exe" "%~dp0\arch\file.nesta"
```

This results (most likely) in an error message as `Drive and path of batch file\Virtua.exe` is interpreted as title and command processor can't find in directory `Drive and path of batch file\arch` a file with name `file.nesta.*` with a file extension listed in environment variable **PATHEXT**.

---

#### Command START with two parameters in quotes in right order and with required title string

```
START "" %~dp0Virtua.exe" "%~dp0arch\file.nesta"
```

This is the right command to start `Virtua.exe` in directory of batch file with `file.nesta` in subfolder `arch` of batch file folder as parameter for `Virtua.exe` and given the console window no title if `Virtua.exe` is a console application.

There is no backslash after `%~dp0` as this string is expanded by command processor always to drive and path of batch file ending already with a backslash before command **START** processes the parameters.

Using `%~dp0\` would result in `\\` between path of batch file folder and for example `Virtua.exe` which is not 100% correct. However, Windows automatically cleans up file and folder strings with `\\` inside and therefore this small mistake would have no effect on execution.

---

#### Summary

1. On specifying **ALWAYS** first a **title** string in double quotes **after START** makes your batch coding life easier.
2. Using `""` for a GUI application and `"Something meaningful"` for a command or console application as title string makes it easier for the users of the batch file to identify what the opened console window is for in list of running applications displayed on using Alt+Tab, in Windows task bar depending on the used task bar options (just symbol displayed or symbol with begin of window title) and in Task Manager of Windows.

**Note:**

There are combinations of not quoted parameters and quoted parameters which do not require a quoted title string. But it is really much easier to specify always a title string instead of finding out when a title string in quotes must be specified and when it is possible to omit it if any parameter is enclosed in quotes.