# Parse file line by line and increment a variable in for loop in Batch

Tags: loops, batch-file

I've been trying all day long to make my work easier by automatizing a flow. Here's what I got so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /l %%x in (1,1,10) do (
        set /a counter=%%x+1
        set output=%%x
        start /wait ffmpeg.exe -i "blabla/playlist.m3u8" -c copy C:\teste\%%x.ts
)
pause >nul
```

`blabla/playlist.m3u8` is always changing (see the below file) and I'd like to rename the stream (link) with an incremented variable so that the first one will become `1.ts`, the second `2.ts` and so on.

Supposing that my file (`streams.txt`) is structerd like this:

```
blabla1/playlist1.m3u8
blabla2/playlist132.m3u8
blabla3/playlist12.m3u8
blabla4/playlist66.m3u8
...
```

How can I parse each line from the file in my `for` loop and rename the stream by incrementing the `%%x` variable ?

// I am aware of the next syntax: `for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do [process] %%A` but I do not know how to actually apply it in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another, simpler way:

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" streams.txt') do (
   ECHO start /wait ffmpeg.exe -i "%%b" -c copy C:\teste\%%a.ts
)
```

The `findstr /N` command enumerates the lines, so it is not necessary to use another variable for the number. The output is:

```
start /wait ffmpeg.exe -i "blabla1/playlist1.m3u8" -c copy C:\teste\1.ts
start /wait ffmpeg.exe -i "blabla2/playlist132.m3u8" -c copy C:\teste\2.ts
start /wait ffmpeg.exe -i "blabla3/playlist12.m3u8" -c copy C:\teste\3.ts
start /wait ffmpeg.exe -i "blabla4/playlist66.m3u8" -c copy C:\teste\4.ts
```

**EDIT**: *New method added as reply to comment*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

< anotherFile.txt (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (streams.txt) do (
      set /P "line="
      ECHO start /wait ffmpeg.exe -i "%%a" -c copy "C:\teste\!line!.ts"
   )
)
```

Output:

```
start /wait ffmpeg.exe -i "blabla1/playlist1.m3u8" -c copy "C:\teste\first-line-of another-file.ts"
start /wait ffmpeg.exe -i "blabla2/playlist132.m3u8" -c copy "C:\teste\second-line-of another-file.ts"
start /wait ffmpeg.exe -i "blabla3/playlist12.m3u8" -c copy "C:\teste\third-line-of another-file.ts"
start /wait ffmpeg.exe -i "blabla4/playlist66.m3u8" -c copy "C:\teste\fourth-line-of another-file.ts"
```

Comment: thanks. Nice solution. What if I'd like instead of numbers to also take a line from another file ? So that the output will be something like `.. copy C:\teste\first-line-of another-file.ts `,  `.. copy C:\teste\second-line-of another-file.ts `.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your objective correctly, this should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET COUNTER=0
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ( streams.txt ) DO (
    SET /A COUNTER+=1
    ECHO START /wait ffmpeg.exe -i "%%G" -c copy C:\teste\!COUNTER!.ts
)
```

The script is inactive, i.e. it just prints out the commands - remove the `ECHO` to activate it. With your example file `streams.txt`, it prints:

```
START /wait ffmpeg.exe -i "blabla1/playlist1.m3u8" -c copy C:\teste\1.ts
START /wait ffmpeg.exe -i "blabla2/playlist132.m3u8" -c copy C:\teste\2.ts
START /wait ffmpeg.exe -i "blabla3/playlist12.m3u8" -c copy C:\teste\3.ts
START /wait ffmpeg.exe -i "blabla4/playlist66.m3u8" -c copy C:\teste\4.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code needed for reading the text file with the file names line by line and use an incremented number:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Counter=0"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("streams.txt") do (
    set /A Counter+=1
    ffmpeg.exe -i "%%~L" -c copy C:\teste\!Counter!.ts
)
endlocal
pause >nul
```

`ffmpeg.exe` is a console application and therefore no need to use `start /wait`.

But if you want to use nevertheless command **start**, you need the line

```
start "" /wait ffmpeg.exe -i "%%~L" -c copy C:\teste\!Counter!.ts
```

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34639508/3074564) to understand why `""` or a meaningful **title** string specified as first double quoted string is very often required after command **start**.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

`!Counter!` instead of `%Counter%` is required to reference the current value of environment variable `Counter` with delayed expansion. `%Counter%` in block defined with `(` ... `)` would result in replacing this string by `0` as defined above the block on parsing entire block. Run `if /?` in a command prompt window for details about delayed expansion explained on a simple example.

See also answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) why assigning a value to a variable should be always done with using double quotes this way: `set "variable=value"`